# CKEditor5 - Wrapping entire contents in a div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor to create content that can be loaded as a template into a generic Vue (still on Vue 2) component like this:

```
<component v-if="html" :is="{template: html}>
```

I need the template loading so the contents can be "live" such as router-links, etc.  In order to use this functionality the html template must have a single root element, but the output value of the CKEditor element will usually have multiple root elements.  Using v-html such as

```
<div v-if="html" v-html="html">
```

does not work because the contents won't be "live", that is, Vue won't wire a router-link tag into the router etc.
Is there a way to get CKEditor to automatically wrap the contents in a div or other arbitrary wrapping element?